# Guice bindings on config changes

Tags: java, dependency-injection, binding, guice, presto

I am using [cfg4j](http://www.cfg4j.org/releases/latest/) library for reflecting the changes in the beans on changes in the config files (auto-reload/refresh)

```
public ConfigurationProvider getConfigurationProvider()
    {
        ConfigFilesProvider configFilesProvider = () -> Arrays.asList(Paths.get("session.properties"));
        ConfigurationSource source = new FilesConfigurationSource(configFilesProvider);
        Environment environment = new ImmutableEnvironment("/home/boss/");
        ReloadStrategy reloadStrategy = new PeriodicalReloadStrategy(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return new ConfigurationProviderBuilder()
                .withConfigurationSource(source)
                .withEnvironment(environment)
                .withReloadStrategy(reloadStrategy)
                .build();
    }

...
//Binding on the class with Provider
   getConfigurationProvider().bind("session-config",SessionConfig.class);
```

Now the existing application also has existing guice binding

```
import static io.airlift.configuration.ConfigBinder.configBinder;
...

Bootstrap app = new Bootstrap(
                    new ClientModule(),
                    binder -> {
                     configBinder(binder).bindConfig(SessionConfig.class);
});
```

My question is : if we add additional binding
                     `getConfigurationProvider().bind("sample-config",SessionConfig.class);`

How can I use the same instance of the class SessionConfig or will the same instance of the class be used in both the bindings?

PS: I am using airlift framework for guice bindings used in presto.